# How to perform $\int_0^\infty4\pi(x+R)^2\left(1-\left(\frac{\frac{x+p}{R}+\tanh{\frac{x+p}{D}}}{\frac{x+p}{R}+1}\right)^2\right)dx\,$?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

This is a continuation to another question i've asked here before. I've found a function that describes the concentration function of a polymer around a sphere. I want to evaluate the following integral that contains that function but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Can someone send me in the right direction, Mathematica is unable to perform the integral. Close approximations would also work. Thank you in advance!

$$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty4\pi(x+R)^2\left(1-\left(\frac{\frac{x+p}{R}+\tanh{\frac{x+p}{D}}}{\frac{x+p}{R}+1}\right)^2\right)dx$$

With $R>0$, $D>0$ and $p \geq 0$.

Edit: I've checked and numerical integration does just fine, so the integral does converge. A plot of the integrand shows that it has a "distribution-like" shape.

Edit 2: As noted in the comments, it seems that complex analysis might be the key. I'm not experienced with any form of complex analysis, if someone is able to get me on the right track it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I've seen expressions nicer that that one in my darkest nightmares...What have you tried so far? What is this horror of integral's background?

Comment: I've tried rewriting it in exponential form, it looks a tad bit easier then but it seems that there is no proper substitution in order to get a "solvable" form. The background is that this is basically the approximate integral of the concentration profile of a polymer around a sphere with radius R. It can be written as 4$\pi$(x+R)^2 (1-f(x))dx, where f(x) is the concentration profile around the sphere.

Comment: Any other approximations we can use? Are any of the variables in the problem very small?

Comment: Other than $D>p$ for all $p$ and $D$, no, sorry.

Comment: Have you checked whether it even converges?

Comment: Yeah numerical integration does just fine and results in the expected values.

Comment: You can get a decent approximation by cutting off at some $x$ such that $\frac{x+p}{D} \gg 1$ and approximating the $\tanh$ by $1$ out there, so that the tail contribution to integration is basically just zero. Similarly you can handle the regime $\frac{x+p}{D} \ll 1$ by approximating the $\tanh$ as just zero, which results in a rational function. But in the middle, $\tanh$ just is what it is, so you're presumably stuck with numerical integration or *maybe* the residue theorem, unless $D$ is so small that the $\tanh$ can be approximated by a step function.

Comment: Yeah I've checked that out and as a very rough first approximation it works decent-ish. I haven't followed any complex analysis courses. I will read up on the residue theorem, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: I think the residue theorem can handle the integral on $[-p,\infty)$. But then you would be left to subtract off the integral on $[-p,0]$.